# Poor video quality in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, graphics, video, window

I installed Ubuntu 16.04 recently and noticed that when I watch some videos, horizontal lines appear in dark regions. I have an Intel display adapter in my Lenovo G50-80 laptop. This hasn't happened with Windows 10. Also, the region near the window is having those lines in the below picture. Please respond asap!

[image]

[image]

Comment: where are these lines I don't see them?

Comment: I can only view them while using Ubuntu.I am using windows 10 now and I can't see those lines.What's wrong with my pc?